# Android driver resets DNS on my Win7 host

Tags: tethering, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, dns

Few days ago I plugged my android (HTC1) phone to my Win7 machine which never had any network issues.

When I connected, I also made th following change:

> Mobile Hotspot & tethering->USB network Setting->Internet pass through

Even when the phone is *disconnected*, from time to time, something (new) resets the DNS setting to my phone's IP address.  I reset with `ipconfig /renew` and it is fine for a while, but eventually flips back.

**Update:**

Ran wireshark on PC and it looks like the phone is sending DHCP ACKs and announcing itself as the router & DNS server etc.

**This can't be a feature, How am I supposed to stop it?**

Comment: Did you run the wireshark capture when the phone was connected via USB?

Comment: @onik, no the phone was no longer connected via USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: I am pretty sure got fixed after I enabled and disabled "Mobile Hotspot"

So while I am answering my own question, I will accept any answer that describes how to disable this faulty behavior